# Lua how to remove ".html" text from end of string

Tags: lua

So I have a string in Lua and I want to remove all occurances ".html" text of the end of the string

```
local lol = ".com/url/path/stuff.html"

print(lol)
```

Output i want :

```
.com/url/path/stuff


local lol2 = ".com/url/path/stuff.html.html"

print(lol2)
```

Output i want :

```
.com/url/path/stuff
```

Comment: bar = lol:gsub("(.*).html.*$","%1")     removes one occurance of the .html text but as the "lol2" variable string example i provided it does not work on that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you could define a function like this:

```
function removeHtmlExtensions(s)
    return s:gsub("%.html", "")
end
```

Then:

```
local lol = ".com/url/path/stuff.html"
local lol2 = ".com/url/path/stuff.html.html"

local path1 = removeHtmlExtensions(lol)
local path2 = removeHtmlExtensions(lol2)

print(path1) -- .com/url/path/stuff
print(path2) -- .com/url/path/stuff
```

There is a second value returned from the `gsub` method that indicates how many times the pattern was matched. It returns, for example, `1` with `path1` and `2` with `path2`. (Just in case that info is useful to you):

```
local path2, occurrences = removeHtmlExtensions(lol2)

print(occurrences) -- 2
```

Comment: Is this also ok i got  this to work too.          bar = lol:gsub(".html.*$","")
print(bar)     the only issue is if the url contains /html/ it removes that too more problems :(

Comment: Since `.` is a special character in string patterns, you should escape it when you pass to `:gsub` as `:gsub("%.html", "")`

Comment: @Curtis, right, of course. Thanks for the fix. Updated.

Comment: that will remove *all* occurrences of '.html' though

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with a tail-recursive function like this:

```
local function foo(bar)
  if bar:find('%.html$') then return foo(bar:sub(1, -5) else return bar end
end
```

in words:

- If *bar* ends in '.html', remove the last 5 characters
  and feed that into foo again (to remove any more occurrences)
- Otherwise, return bar as it is

Benefits:

- Tail recursive, so it can't overflow the stack even for very long chains '.html'
- `string.find` is pretty fast when you anchor the search to the end of the string with `$`
- `string.sub` is also rather fast compared to, for example, `string.gsub` (note that those two do completely different things, despite the similar name).