# How do I check the file format correctly with Lua?

Tags: file, lua, format, pattern-matching

I want to create a function that would receive a table of strings of files and it would sort them so that it was returning only .png files. I tried to do this using `string.match()` and use a `%.png` pattern, but as long as this string contains ".png" wherever in it, it would work incorrectly.

```
local file_list = {
    "image1.png",       -- sucess
    "image2.jpg",       -- fail
    "image3.png.gif"    -- unwanted, but will pass
}

-- sorting function
for i, j in ipairs(file_list) do
    if not string.match(j, "%.png") then
        table.remove(file_list, i)
    end
end

-- print the output
for i, j in pairs(file_list) do
    print(i, j)
end
```

Although `table.remove()` is slow, I am using it here to free the space.

So how do I check the file format correctly? I didn't find a way to continue the string matching till the string ends. Of course I could just check it out with `string.sub(j, -4, -1)`, but it doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Comment: `string.match(string.lower(j), "%.png$")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua how to remove ".html" text from end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889475/3832970)

Comment: Oops, I forgot about "$" sign... Thanks a lot!